# C# TCP Client Error if I reach listener.start

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Can someone help me please ? 
Thats the error if i reach listener.start
But I have no open tcp connection.
Error:
{ " Normally each socket address ( protocol , network address or port ) are used only once " }

Stack Trace = " at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind ( EndPoint endPointSnapshot , SocketAddress socket address ) \ r \ n at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind ( EndPoint localEP ) \ r \ n at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener .Start ( Int32 backlog ) \ r \ n at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListene ...

[image: Thats my Code]

```
    const int PORT_NO = 3242;
    const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";

public static void send()
{
    IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
    try
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + Info.MainFile);
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close(); 
        //Hier den string rein geben !
        byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        listener.Start();
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        //int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Console.WriteLine("Received : " + dataReceived);
        Console.WriteLine("Sending back : " + dataReceived);
        //nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Count());
        //client.Close();
        listener.Stop();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + Info.Log, true);
        //sw.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        //sw.Flush();
        //sw.Close();
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the complete error message you get?

Comment: Stack Trace = " at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind ( EndPoint endPointSnapshot , SocketAddress socket address ) \ r \ n at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind ( EndPoint localEP ) \ r \ n at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener .Start ( Int32 backlog ) \ r \ n at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListene ...

Comment: You can edit that into your question.  It doesn't really work well to put code in comments :\

Answer (score 1):

This might happen if the port is already taken. 
It is possible that previous debug sessions were not closed properly or the listening socket was not closed.

You could run

> netstat -ab

to see currently open connections or connection that are in WAIT or LISTENING state.

Try to change the port to see if it works.

Comment: { " Access to a socket was due to the access rights of the sockets inadmissible " } thats the next Problem if i reach listener.start

Comment: And the next error is "null" if i reach listener.start

Comment: It is possible that your are blocked by an antivirus software or firewall?

Comment: No i dont install any antivirus software

Comment: Could try to disable Windows firewall ? or maybe you could you run the app 'As Administrator'.